# Read numeric input data from argv and store into an array of int in C

Tags: c, arrays, integer, arguments, argv

How can I read triples of numbers from the program arguments into an array of integers and then display them? That is I enter `./read 1,2,3 4,5,6 7,8,9` and the ouptput should be

`1 2 3`

`4 5 6`

`7 8 9`

My code works well only for strings, but not integers

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int i;
  int d[argc][3];
  int x[3];
  for(i = 1; i < argc; i ++){
      char *a[3];
      int j = 0;
      a[j] = strtok(argv[i], ",");
      while(a[j] != NULL){
        a[++j] = strtok(NULL, ",");
        x[j] = atoi(&(a[j]));
      }
      printf("%s %s %s \n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
      printf("%d %d %d \n", x[0], x[1], x[2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It displays `1 0 0` on each line.

Comment: Note: `,` between `3,4`, but not `6 7`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `int d[argc][3];`?

Comment: `x[j] = atoi(a[j]);` then `a[++j] = strtok(NULL, ",");`

Comment: also `a[3]` is out of bounds.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh: right, that's a piece that doesn't belong there

Comment: when writing variable names, use meaningful names.  the `a` `x` `d` are not meaningful, even in the current context.

Comment: when `strtok()` fails, then this line: `x[j] = atoi(&(a[j]));` (which is written incorrectly, it should be; `x[j] = atoi(a[j]);` will be accessing memory at address 0.   This is almost certain to result in a `access violation` seg fault event.  I.E. always check (!=NULL) the returned value from `strtok()` before de-referencing that value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Here you have an error

   ```
   x[j] = atoi(&(a[j]));
   ```

   you should not pass the address like that, just

   ```
   x[j] = atoi(a[j]);
   ```

   should work.
2. You must include *stdlib.h*
3. You must check against `NULL` after `strtok()`. Or to do it correctly follow [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752825/read-numeric-input-data-from-argv-and-store-into-an-array-of-int-in-c/34752860#comment57251843_34752825) by @[BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy).

   > `x[j] = atoi(a[j]);` then `a[++j] = strtok(NULL, ",");`

Enabling compiler warnings should have let you find this yourself.